# Asynctask crashing unecpectedly

Tags: java, android

wishing you are having nice day.

Im working on an application and I just wanted to change my activities' name and I think I did all true. My app's old build is working really good, with no problems but I just changed my class' name and my app started to crash unexpectedly.

```
class DownloadFilesTaskGet extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object>
    {

        @Override

        public String doInBackground(String... HOS)  {
            String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
            String url = "http://qpython.net";
            for(int i = 0; i < HOS.length; i++){
                String BOS = HOS[i].trim();
                if(BOS.isEmpty() == false){
                    try{
                        URL obj = new URL(url);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                        con.setRequestProperty("Host", BOS);    
                        con.setRequestProperty("X-Online-Host", BOS);   
                        int ki = i+1;
                        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                        String durum;
                        if(responseCode == 200){durum = "ÇALIŞIYOR";}else{durum="ÇALIŞMIYOR";}
                        publishProgress( BOS+ " - " + durum+"\n",ki+"/"+HOS.length);
                    }
                    catch(IOException e){
                        String durum = "ÇALIŞMIYOR";
                        int ki = i+1;
                        publishProgress( BOS+ " - " + durum+"\n",ki,HOS.length);
                    }
                }       
            }
        return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            TextView Std = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Std);
            TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sonuc);
            Switch SecH = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.SdcH);
            String econf = values[1]+"/"+values[2];
            String val = values[0].toString();
            Std.setText(econf);
            if(SecH.isChecked() == true){
                if(val.contains("MIYOR")){
                    display.append("hm");
                }
                else{
                    display.append(values[0]+"\n");
                }
            }
            else{
                display.append(values[0]+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a result as "de.blinkt.openvpn ÇALIŞIYOR"  or ÇALIŞMIYOR. Or I expect. But when it's time to say "ÇALIŞIYOR" my app crashes...

My logcat

```
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   Process: dr.war.host, PID: 12243
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at dr.war.host.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTaskGet.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:120)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:648)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-27 20:50:23.032 12243 12243 E   AndroidRuntime dr.war.host                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

It seems error is at String econf = values[1]+"/"+values[2]; but there's nothing to be mistaken...

Comment: Did you update the name of the Activity in your manifest?

Comment: @SaravInfern Added my logcat.

Comment: @Katharina Yes. Also I created a new application and pasted all code into it, but still getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in the `try`

```
ki+"/"+HOS.length);
```

Where in the `catch` you have

```
ki,HOS.length);
```

In the second case, `values[1] = ki` and `values[2] = HOS.length`. It is the first case that you have the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only 2 arguments in `publishProgress`:

```
publishProgress( BOS+ " - " + durum+"\n",ki+"/"+HOS.length);
```

but, you are trying to read values with indexes 1 and 2:

```
String econf = values[1]+"/"+values[2];
```

The value with index 2 never exists - array contains only two values, at index 0 and 1.

Comment: Oh, how stupid I am :) Thank you for help :) I just made a mistake. I just forgot to split the val2 on first publishing but I did it on second one. Thanks for support :)